# Inheritance with template classes and interfaces

Tags: c++, class, templates, interface, queue

Goal: Implement queue.
Problem: Unable to instantiate "OurQueue" class
*note: class "OurQueue" is also supposed to have:

```
queue();                // Default constructor
bool empty() const ;             // Tests whether the queue is empty
void push(const ItemType& newEntry);    // Adds newEntry to the back of the queue
void pop();                 // Removes the front of the queue
ItemType& front();          // Returns a reference to the front of the queue
```

(but I can't even instantiate it so I haven't added these)

Interface:

```
/** @file QueueInterface.h */

#ifndef _QUEUE_INTERFACE
#define _QUEUE_INTERFACE

template<class ItemType>
class QueueInterface

{
public:
   /** Sees whether this queue is empty.
    @return True if the queue is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Adds a new entry to the back of this queue.
    @post If the operation was successful, newEntry is at the 
       back of the queue.
    @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry.
    @return True if the addition is successful or false if not. */
   virtual bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;

   /** Removes the front of this queue.
    @post If the operation was successful, the front of the queue 
       has been removed.
    @return True if the removal is successful or false if not. */
   virtual bool dequeue() = 0;

   /** Returns the front of this queue.
    @pre The queue is not empty.
    @post The front of the queue has been returned, and the
       queue is unchanged.
    @return The front of the queue. */
   virtual ItemType peekFront() const = 0;
   virtual ~QueueInterface(){};
}; // end QueueInterface
#endif
```

ArrayQueue header file

```
    /** ADT queue: Circular array-based implementation.
 @file ArrayQueue.h */

#ifndef _ARRAY_QUEUE
#define _ARRAY_QUEUE

#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"
#include "ArrayQueue.cpp"

const int MAX_QUEUE = 50;

template<class ItemType>
class ArrayQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
   ItemType items[MAX_QUEUE]; // Array of queue items
   int front;                 // Index to front of queue
   int back;                  // Index to back of queue
   int count;                 // Number of items currently in the queue

public:
   ArrayQueue();   
   // Copy constructor and destructor supplied by compiler

   bool isEmpty() const;
   bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry);
   bool dequeue();

   /** @throw PrecondViolatedExcep if queue is empty. */
   ItemType peekFront() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
}; // end ArrayQueue
#endif
```

OurQueue class implementation and main file

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "ArrayQueue.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

using namespace std;


template<class ItemType>
class OurQueue : public ArrayQueue<ItemType> {
    OurQueue(){};               // Default constructor
};


int main() {

    QueueInterface<int>*listPtr = new ArrayQueue<int>(); //but it this throws error
    //QueueInterface<int>* listPtr2 = new OurQueue<int>(); //but it this throws error


    cout << listPtr->isEmpty() << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

ArrayQueue implementation file:

```
/** ADT queue: Circular array-based implementation. @file ArrayQueue.cpp */

    #include "ArrayQueue.h"  // Header file

    template<class ItemType>
    ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue() : front(0), back(MAX_QUEUE - 1), count(0)
    {
    } // end default constructor

    template<class ItemType>
    bool ArrayQueue<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
    {
       return count == 0;
    } // end isEmpty

    template<class ItemType>
    bool ArrayQueue<ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry)
    {
       bool result = false;
       if (count < MAX_QUEUE)
       {
          // Queue has room for another item
          back = (back + 1) % MAX_QUEUE;
          items[back] = newEntry;
          count++;
          result = true;
       } // end if

       return result;
    } // end enqueue

    template<class ItemType>
    bool ArrayQueue<ItemType>::dequeue()
    {
       bool result = false;
       if (!isEmpty())
       {
          front = (front + 1) % MAX_QUEUE;
          count--;
          result = true;
       } // end if

       return result;
    } // end dequeue

    template<class ItemType>
    ItemType ArrayQueue<ItemType>::peekFront() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep)
    {
       // Enforce precondition
       if (isEmpty())
          throw PrecondViolatedExcep("peekFront() called with empty queue");

       // Queue is not empty; return front
       return items[front];
    } // end peekFront
    // End of implementation file.
```

I get an error that is something like:

```
 ArrayQueue.cpp:7:1: error: redefinition of 'ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue()'
 ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue() : front(0), back(MAX_QUEUE - 1), count(0)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ArrayQueue.h:31,
                 from ArrayQueue.cpp:3:
ArrayQueue.cpp:7:1: note: 'ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue()' previously declared here
 ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue() : front(0), back(MAX_QUEUE - 1), count(0)`enter code here`
```

Comment: `#include "ArrayQueue.cpp"` is almost always a bad idea. If this is a template's implementation file give it a different extension and save cpp for use by files that will be compiled and linked.

Comment: Warning `QueueInterface` needs a virtual destructor. Without it all sorts of undefined wackiness can happen when you delete a `OurQueue` from a `QueueInterface *`

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see: you have to specify the template for the class you're extending

```cpp
template <typename ItemType>
class OurQueue : public ArrayQueue<ItemType>
```

(and so forth)

Comment: This seems to have helped. But I'm still getting the issues of constructor redefinition.

Comment: If you're using `#include "ArrayQueue.cpp"` in multiple places, that might duplicate the code and cause that error.

Traditionally, you're supposed to compile implementation files separately: `gcc file1.cpp file2.cpp etc.cpp` and not link them to each other with #include.

Comment: OHHHH someone else was saying something about that too! Okay that makes sense. After what you said I slapped a pragma once at the top of "ArrayQueue.cpp" and was able to get rid of those errors. I should probably just compile separately though.

Comment: Nice. Pay attention to that comment about the virtual destructor too. If the destructor isn't virtual, and you downcast to the virtual base class, it won't know how to clean up all the junk allocated by the derived classes.

Comment: hm...so I made it so everything is compiled separately and it stopped working. I still have to include the header files right? Just not the .ccp files...that way my ide knows what I'm talking about. When I do this I get the same redefinition errors as before.

Comment: Each cpp file should `#include` all the headers it needs. All headers should have either guards or `#pragma once` at the top. The header shouldn't contain the body to any function, or initialize any static variable (though there are exceptions)

Comment: Yeah they all do yet redefinition still happens and I don't know why.

Comment: What is your current error message? The one in the main description still looks like you're `#include`ing ArrayQueue.cpp from ArrayQueue.h, which is the opposite relationship.

Comment: I made sure I wasn't incuding ArrayQueue.cpp form ArrayQueue.h and added {} braces to Ourclass to make sure but none of the other function are found...the functions that are supposed to be inherited. I get errors that are undefined reference to all the ArrayQueue functions

Comment: Ok, I see - you've got templated code, and that's messing up the traditional header/implementation file split. Templated code doesn't really exist, it's just a blueprint for the compiler to generate something when some code lays down `ArrayQueue<int> example;`. Because of that, it's pretty common to just put the whole implementation, in-class, in the header file, and *not even have a .cpp*. You don't even pass it to the compiler, it will be automatically generated when another class uses it.

Comment: If possible I would like you to remove your comment and instead post it as an answer because that is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, I see a typo:

```
template<class ItemType>
class OurQueue : public ArrayQueue<ItemType> {
    OurQueue();                 // Default constructor
};
```

The constructor name was `Ourqueue` instead of `OurQueue`

Second:

These files should look something like this:

`ArrayQueue.cpp`

```
#include "ArrayQueue.h"

template<class ItemType>
ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue()
{
    //implementation
}

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueue<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return true;
    //implementation
}

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueue<ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    return true;
    //implementation
}

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueue<ItemType>::dequeue()
{
    return true;
    //implementation
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Notice that I included the header and not the cpp
#include "ArrayQueue.h"

// Please don't use this. <.<
// using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class OurQueue : public ArrayQueue<ItemType> {
public:
    OurQueue()
    {

    }
};

int main() 
{
    QueueInterface<int>*listPtr = new OurQueue<int>(); //but it this throws error
    std::cout << listPtr->isEmpty() << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

I compiled them using clang:

`clang++ main.cpp ArrayQueue.h`

Compiled without any errors! You dont need to compile QueueInterface as it does not have any definitions. You can add it to compilation list though. It won't give any errors.

Comment: why do you compile the header files if they are already included ?

Comment: You compile the files which have definitions. Header files usually just contain declarations. In your case however, the arrayqueue.h file also contains definitions (it includes arrayqueue.cpp). You dont need to compile arrayqueue.cpp as it will be included in the header and you are already compiling the header.

Comment: @cmaga The definitions are templated functions they will be compiled when they are used. No need to compile them separately [except in rare circumstances](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). This is the sort of nonsense that happens when you use the cpp extension for stuff that shouldn't be compiled. Someone (or something) compiles them by mistake.

Comment: I have edited and made some corrections. I am compiling all of the .cpp files individually and tying them together using only header files. but my types aren't being recognized. See the last part of the question for the error messages.